# How to improve the way that comments are shown in a chat box JavaScript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I’ve made a chat box but, I have a problem when I delete an unwanted comment. I have a delete function associate to an onclick event for each comment inserted
This is how I show the comments:
(Comments are stored in a data base )

```
var refreshMsg = setInterval(function() {
    $.post("chatFunc.php", { action: "load", id_userMsg: '<?php echo $id_user; ?>' },
function(dVLoadUsers) {
$("#divMsg").append(dVLoadUsers);   // appending the new comments into a div        $("#divMsg").scrollTop($("#divMsg")[0].scrollHeight);   
        }); 
}, 399); // Loop time in milliseconds
```

This is the delete function(jquery):

```
function DeleteMsg(id_msg){
$.post("chatFunc.php", { action: "del", id_msgChat: id_msg, id_userMsg: '<?php echo $id_user; ?>' },
    function(dVLoad) {
        $("#divMsg").html(dVLoad);
        $("#inputMsg").val("").focus();
    }); 
}
```

This is action: “del” in php:

```
if($action == "del"){
$msgDeleted = "Comment Deleted";
$qBorraMsj = mysqli_query($classDB->con,"UPDATE chat SET message = '$msgDeleted ' WHERE id LIKE '$id_msgChat'"); // Updating message content to "Comment Deleted"
$qChat = mysqli_query($classDB->con,"SELECT id, message, userNameFROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 60"); // Getting the last 60 messages inserted
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qChat) ){
    if($row['message'] == $msgDeleted ) // Showing deleted messages
        echo '<span class="styleUsName">'.$row['userName'].'</span>:&nbsp;<span class="styleMsgDel">'.$row['message'].'</span></br>';
    else // Showing the rest of the messages
        echo '<span class="styleUsName">'.$row['userName'].'</span>:&nbsp;<span class="styleMsgDel">'.$row['message'].'</span>&nbsp;<span class="styleDelMsg" onClick="deleteMsg('.$row['id'].')">delete</span></br>';
 }
}
```

So, basically when a message is deleted the div is reloaded with the last 60 messages inserted. It works for the guy who is deleting messages but not for everyone, because only him is executing the code.

How can I refresh the panel with messages for everybody ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Store the last `id` sent to the client in a variable and when 'refreshing' use that to limit the query?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to improve the loop function, I don't know how facebook shows messages but, it's not a perma refresh. I think it's a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745573/jon) suggests, you could send the ID of the most recent message that has been displayed to the server and then only get messages that are newer than that. You would then `.append()` the new message/s rather than clearing out the whole div with `.load()`.

Comment: That's a good idea, adding the new messages into div besides reloading everything.

The other problem is the loop function, I think is a waste of resources refreshing constantly. I'm mind-blocked in how to show to everybody when a new message is posted without refreshing every second. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at http://meteor.com/ then. Unfortunately in a lot of cases, polling (or looping) is the only option.

Comment: Thanks bro, I'd vote up your answer but, I need more reputation hehehe

Comment: I can upvote though. ^^ @user2088447 if this answer is one that you think answers your question the best, you should accept it so other will be more willing to answer your questions in the future. ^^

Comment: Yeah, and that meteor platform looks very useful